# Reopen queue audit failed because the question had been migrated

Tags: bug, status-completed, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

I made one of my occasional forays into the review queues and failed this audit:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/10929687

The question had 8 up votes but had been migrated and showed up as being migrated in the review. As such my natural inclination was to hit the "leave closed" option. However, this was "wrong" (in the eyes of the audit) because of the question score.

So either:

1. Migrated questions should be excluded from the audit process.

or:

2. The "[migrated]" in the title should be replaced by "[on hold]" and another reason substituted.

or:

3. Change the rules so that "leave closed" is the correct behaviour in this case.

Comment: Link to the migration stub on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34799809/permutation-of-list-in-python-so-that-listx-x1?noredirect=1

Comment: This should've been excluded for multiple reasons; I'm not sure what happened here, but I'll dig into it momentarily.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Near as I can tell, this is a caching issue.

The criteria for a "known-good" audit in the reopen queue are:

- Score between 5 and 15 (inclusive)
- Recently created
- No recent downvotes
- No bounties
- **No close votes, ever**
- Lots of views
- **Not locked**
- **Not migrated**
- **Not closed**
- Not deleted

Items in bold are criteria that *were* met... Until two days ago when George migrated it to Code Review. That action immediately resulted in **four** changes to the state of the post which should've disqualified it.

However, post IDs for audits are cached. It's possible that this particular post was cached prior to George closing it, and managed to *stay* in the cache for another day after it should've been disqualified. That... Seems pretty unlikely, but it's the only plausible cause I can come up with here.

The solution would be to perform a sanity-check on audits prior to assigning them to a reviewer, similar to what's done for *normal* posts assigned in the reopen queue, discarding those that no longer qualify.

Comment: I think the sanity check would be useful.  Bounty question still get used from time to time as well and I think it is to do with the bounty being newer then the selection of the "know good" audit.

Comment: Still happening :( http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/316284/792066

Answer (score 7):

> The "[migrated]" in the title should be replaced by "[on hold]" and another reason substituted.

"migrated" *is appropriate* because that's the most accurate description of the state of the post.  That shouldn't change.

> Migrated questions should be excluded from the audit process.

Well, they don't need to be excluded, they simply need to be treated, by the audit selection criteria, as being off topic.  For a post to be migrated it needs to be off topic on the source site, meaning that *it merits closure on that site*.  So using a migrated question would be fine, if it's used as an example of a question that *should be closed as off topic*.

That said, because migrated questions ought to be question that are of high quality, other than for just being off topic, they're likely not going to make as good of audits as the very clearly poor quality questions that would be more unambiguously garbage.

You're absolutely right though that they should never be used as an example of a "good" question that shouldn't be closed, because they are, by definition, off topic.

Answer (score 3):

Classical case of [shouldiblamecaching.com](http://shouldiblamecaching.com/). A fix will that verify the audit is sill valid before showing it to the user is rolling out in the next build (build rev `2016.5.4.4471` on MSE/MSO, `2016.5.4.3536` on sites). This bug was specific to the close and reopen review queues.