# Close queue audits still select questions with bounties... _active bounties_

Tags: bug, review-audits

[This review](//stackoverflow.com/review/close/11164238) with an active bounty for more than 4 days have appeared in the close queue. This was supposedly fixed and some sanity checks being implemented before [showing the audit](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/315069/792066), so I call shenanigans!

[image]